# Difficulties when replacing char in string in C using pointers

Tags: c

I'm working my way through `C Programming: A Modern Approach` but I'm having a bit of trouble with the last exercise of the chapter on strings.

I'm trying to replace a character in a string with a null character to remove the file_name but I keep getting a bus error and I don't understand what I am doing wrong:

```c
void remove_filename(char *url)
{
  char *last_slash;

  while (*url++)
    if (*url == '/')
      last_slash = url;

  *last_slash = '\0';
}
```

The way I see it, I am keeping track of the address of the last slash (in the `last_slash` pointer). Then I target the object stored at that address and replace it by a `null` character.

Any feedback as to why my reasoning is false is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. For example, we do not know what string you are passing to the function. But for starters, consider what value `last_slash` will be if there is no `/` character in the string.

Comment: `(*url++)
    if (*url` you are omitting first character. You have to increment after checking.

Comment: Also, `lastslash` is never initialized, and contains random bits. If you never find a '/', you will write your '\0' wildly somewhere in to memory.

Comment: regarding: `(*url++)`   This has a precedence problem.  Suggest:  `( (*url)++)`  so the target variable is incremented rather than the `url` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `last_slash` so that you can properly check if a `'/'` was found after the loop. Restructure the loop to only move the pointer after first checking the value it points to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void remove_filename(char *url)
{
  char *last_slash = NULL;

  for (; *url; url++)
      if (*url == '/')
          last_slash = url;

  if (last_slash)
      *last_slash = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "path/to/some/file.data";

    printf("<<%s>> -> ", buffer);
    remove_filename(buffer);
    printf("<<%s>>\n", buffer);
}
```

Output:

```
<<path/to/some/file.data>> -> <<path/to/some>>
```